# Scale image for canvas use in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas

I am building a website in which the user can upload an image, and edit it in a canvas. Right now this is my code:

Upload:

```
const handleChange = async e => {
    const {files} = e.target;
    const file = files[0];
    setImage(file);
};

<input id={'fileInput'} value={filePath} 
   onChange={handleChange} type="file" accept=".jpeg, .jpg" capture="camera"/>
```

Taking the size:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
        const {result} = e.target;
        const {setEditedImage, setCanvasWidth, setCanvasHeight, setOriginalImage} = this.props;
        const image = document.getElementById('image');
        setOriginalImage(result);
        setEditedImage(result);
        if (image) {
            const {naturalHeight, naturalWidth} = image;
            setCanvasWidth(naturalWidth);
            setCanvasHeight(naturalHeight);
        }
    };
    try {
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.props.image);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('caught', e);
    }
}

<img style={{display: 'block', width: '100%'}} id={'image'} src={this.props.originalImage} alt={''}/>
```

So here, I am taking the dataURL and putting it into the Redux state, along with the width and height.

Canvas:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.drawImage(nextProps.width, nextProps.height, nextProps.editedImage)
}

drawImage = (width, height, image) => {
    this.ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    };
    img.src = image
};

handleClick = (e) => {
    const makeDrawing = (canvas) => {
        this.Draw(e.pageX - 305  - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY-100 - canvas.offsetTop);
    };
    const {textLength, tasks} = this.props;
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (textLength === 'over200' || textLength === 'under200') {
        if (tasks !== 0) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    makeDrawing(canvas);
    this.props.setTasks(tasks + 1);

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    this.props.setImageURL(canvas.toDataURL());
    this.props.setEditedImage(img);
};

Draw = (x, y) => {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    // x, y are the cords, 5 is the radius of the circle and the last 2 things specify full circle.
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.lastX = x;
    this.lastY = y;
};

<canvas onClick={this.handleClick} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} id={'canvas'}/>
```

The problem is this:

[image]

The smaller image on the top is the `<ImageContainer/>`. The one below is the `<CanvasContainer/>`. As you can see, even though I set the width to 100% of the modal, canvas ignores this and goes with the width and height found in the base image.

If I set the canvas width to 100% of the parent, it cuts part of the image of. How can I get the canvas to draw scaled images? Always having 100% of the parent's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing `naturalHeight` to `offsetHeight` and `naturalWidth` to `offsetWidth`